# implement doublyLinkedList sorted

Tags: sorting, doubly-linked-list

I'm having trouble implementing a sort on a doublylinkedlist. Below I have the code for inserting into a doublylinkedlist, and the code for a quick sort on a list, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
void sortedList::insertElement(listItemType newItem)
{

    listNode *prev = NULL;
    listNode *cur = head;

    while ((cur != NULL) && (newItem > cur->item))
    {
       prev = cur;
       cur = cur->next;
    }

    listNode *newPtr = new listNode;
    newPtr->item = newItem;

    newPtr->next = cur;

    if (prev == NULL)
        head = newPtr;
        tail->prev = newPtr;
    else
        prev->next = newPtr;

    size++;
}
```

Comment: You may want to add c++ as a tag to this question as this appears to be more of a language-related problem than an algorithmic one.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not put up any code as to where you declare and how you use *tail* attribute of sortedList class, I can not say anything regarding your assignment to it in your second if statement. But short of your lack of usage of curly braces in your first if statement in insertElement function, everything seems to be fine. You can correct it as follows.

```
if (prev == NULL) {
    head = newPtr;
    tail->prev = newPtr;
}
else
    prev->next = newPtr;
```

If your problem is not solved, you may want to edit your question to share minimal amount of extra information of your sortedList, and some more code you use in it so that I can regenerate it.